# My code for rendering random polgons is not working properly

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glut, glu

I'm working on opengl c++ and tried to make a code for rendering random polygons on an terminal. I'm using CodeBlocks 13.12.

```
int width=800;
int height=600;

void RandomPolygons()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLint x[100],y[100],n,r,g,b;
    GLint i,j;
    cout<<"Enter the sides of the polygon to be displayed:"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        x[i]=rand()%800;
        cout<<"x["<<i<<"]=  "<<x[i]<<endl;
        y[i]=rand()%600;
        cout<<"y["<<i<<"]=  "<<y[i]<<endl;
    }
    x[i]=x[1];
    cout<<"x["<<i<<"]=  "<<x[i]<<endl;
    y[i]=y[1];
    cout<<"y["<<i<<"]=  "<<y[i]<<endl;

    r=rand()%2;
    g=rand()%2;
    b=rand()%2;

    glColor3f(r,g,b);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
    {
        glVertex2i(x[j],y[j]);
    }
    glVertex2i(x[j],y[j]);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    glutInit(&argc,argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH|GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(width,height);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow("Random_Polygons!!!!");
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    gluOrtho2D(0,800,0,600);
    glutDisplayFunc(RandomPolygons);
    glutIdleFunc(RandomPolygons);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

**output**

It's just not responding(Rendering screen) and on the other hand terminal is working fine....

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `std::cin` blocks until the user has entered something. Since the application is blocked, the windows message loop is not executed and the window stops responding.

When you need input in a OpenGL application, you will have to listen to `glutKeyboardFunc` and `glutSpecialFunc` and construct the input from there.

Answer (score 0):

1. **I agree with @BDL**

   The `cin` **blocks the processing**... You should **separate** vertex **generation** and polygon **rendering**. Now you are calling Random polygons without predefined **seed** that will change the vertexes each frame making a **blurry mess**. Not to mention wanting keyboard input from user each frame
2. **on top of all that**

   you are creating random points as vertexes which does not always create **convex** polygon which OpenGL can not handle properly. To avoid problems use `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` instead of `GL_POLYGON` and sort the vertexes by angle (or generate them sorted already) for example something like:

   ```
   GLfloat x[100],y[100],a,r;
   GLint i,n=5;
   randseed(10); // init random generator with some value or do this not inside rendering instead
   for (i=0,a=0.0;i<n;a+=rand(6.28/n),i++)  
    {
    r=rand(0.5);
    x[i]=r*cos(a);
    y[i]=r*sin(a);
    }
   // render
   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
   glVertex2f(0.0,0.0);
   for (i=0;i<n;i++)  glVertex2f(x[i],y[i]);
   glVertex2f(x[0],y[0]);
   glEnd();
   ```

   or throw away vertexes turning your polygon into **concave** one.

   - see [How to generate random vertices to form a convex polygon in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21724845/2521214)